# Splicing Date Periods in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need a solution for merging date periods in SQL Server.

The below sets up the working example.  I have two tables, the first holding a single period for a particular product, the second holding smaller periods that fall within the related period from the first table.  I need to merge the two so that I end up with a list of all the contiguous periods covering the original period when including the smaller periods.  I’ve included a sample of the desired result.

Rules:

- There would only ever be a single row in the first table per product
- The rows in the second table would never overlap for a product
- The rows in the second table would only ever fall on or within the boundaries of the original period

```
declare @x table (product varchar(10), fromdate date, todate date) -- forecast
declare @y table (product varchar(10), fromdate date, todate date) -- purchases
declare @z table (product varchar(10), fromdate date, todate date) -- result

insert  @x values ('lrecs', '20150101', '20161231')
insert  @x values ('srecs', '20150701', '20161231')

insert  @y values ('lrecs', '20150401', '20150630')
insert  @y values ('lrecs', '20160101', '20160630')
insert  @y values ('srecs', '20160101', '20161231')

/*
product fromdate    todate
------------------------------
lrecs   2015-01-01  2015-03-31
lrecs   2015-04-01  2015-06-30
lrecs   2015-07-01  2015-12-31
lrecs   2016-01-01  2016-06-30
lrecs   2016-07-01  2016-12-31
srecs   2015-07-01  2015-12-31
srecs   2016-01-01  2016-12-31
*/
```

Comment: I'm working on a solution using nested cursors but I'm struggling with it and I was wondering if anyone else had either done something similar or had any ideas about how best to attack it.

Comment: try while loop instead. it is faster

Comment: @Sushil, that's not really true. A `WHILE` loop is still a `CURSOR`. See this [article](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/26/bad-habits-to-kick-thinking-a-while-loop-isnt-a-cursor) for details.

Comment: What version of SQL Server you use? In SQL Server 2012+ there are `LEAD` and `LAG` functions that help to solve this "gaps and islands" problem efficiently.

Comment: thanks @wewesthemenace. its a nice article. cleared my misconception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SQL 2012 and Above Solution

I'll admit I have not done extensive testing on this to make sure it works in all situations, but it works for your sample data set. It is a recursive/loop/cursor-free solution. Check it out and let me know if it needs any tweaks or if you have any questions.

```
--Combines the tables
;WITH CTE_Union
AS
(
    SELECT product,fromdate,todate
    FROM @y
    UNION ALL
    SELECT product,fromdate,NULL
    FROM @x
    UNION ALL
    SELECT product,NULL,todate
    FROM @x
),
--forms most of the ranges
CTE_range
AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            next_fromdate = LEAD(fromdate,1) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY fromdate)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  product,
                fromdate = COALESCE(fromdate,DATEADD(DAY,1,LAG(todate,1) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY todate))),
                todate = COALESCE(todate,DATEADD(DAY,-1,LEAD(fromdate,1) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY fromdate)))
        FROM CTE_Union
    ) A
    WHERE fromdate < todate
)

SELECT  product,
        fromdate,
        todate
FROM CTE_range
UNION ALL
--fills in the gaps
SELECT product,DATEADD(DAY,1,todate),DATEADD(DAY,-1,next_fromdate)
FROM CTE_range
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,todate,next_fromdate) != 1 --so where there is a gap
ORDER BY product,fromdate
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan, I was unfamiliar with LEAD and LAG, this is a far more elegant solution than I would have come up with.

Answer (score 0):

The `TrimmedRanges` cte just uses table @x to 'trim' each of the ranges in table @y. Then the `CombinedRanges` cte looks for adjacent ranges and creates new ranges covering them both. It does this recursively. Finally, the `MostComprehensiveRanges` cte pulls out only the ranges that aren't encompassed by other ranges.

Note depending on the amount of data you're processing, you may need to use the `OPTION (MAXRECURSION ##)` query hint.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

```
declare @x table (product varchar(10), fromdate date, todate date) -- forecast

declare @y table (product varchar(10), fromdate date, todate date) -- purchases

declare @z table (product varchar(10), fromdate date, todate date) -- result

insert  @x values ('lrecs', '20150101', '20161231')
insert  @x values ('srecs', '20150701', '20161231')

insert  @y values ('lrecs', '20141201', '20150331')
insert  @y values ('lrecs', '20150401', '20150630')
insert  @y values ('lrecs', '20150701', '20150731')
insert  @y values ('lrecs', '20150801', '20150831')
insert  @y values ('lrecs', '20160101', '20160630')
insert  @y values ('srecs', '20160101', '20161231')

;with TrimmedRanges as (
  select
    a.product,
    case when a.fromdate < b.fromdate then b.fromdate else a.fromdate end fromdate,
    case when a.todate > b.todate then b.todate else a.todate end todate
  from
    @y a
    join @x b on a.product = b.product
),
CombinedRanges as (
  select product, fromdate, todate from TrimmedRanges
  union all
  select a.product, a.fromdate, b.todate
  from
    TrimmedRanges a
    join CombinedRanges b
      on a.product = b.product
      and b.fromdate = dateadd(d, 1, a.todate)
),
MostComprehensiveRanges as (
  select a.*
  from CombinedRanges a
  where
    not exists (
      select 1
      from CombinedRanges b
      where
        a.product = b.product
        and (
          ( a.fromdate > b.fromdate and a.fromdate < b.todate )
          or ( a.todate > b.fromdate and a.todate < b.todate )
        )
    )
)
select * from MostComprehensiveRanges
order by product, fromdate
```

Comment: Thanks JC - I didn't spend a lot of time checking why but I only got three rows back from your solution.  Regardless, I have accepted a solution from Stephan.